# QGIS - Shapefile to GeoJSON - way to fix overlapping lines

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I have this file with UK postcode districts in Shapefile: https://www.opendoorlogistics.com/wp-content/uploads/Data/UK-postcode-boundaries-Jan-2015-topojson/Districts.json

I converted it to GeoJSON with the following settings
[image]

However, when I preview the GeoJSON, I see that there are some erros in overlapping lines.
[image]

I see that some of those problems also do exist in Shapefile, some don't. Is there a way to fix them?

-- edit

Same fragment from Shapefile
[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that these shapes were correct in shp? From my point of view this is the result of digitizing not accurate enough and it's nothing related to changing the file format.

Comment: Try using a valid projection rather than an invalid one, then look at `topology-checker` plugin

Comment: @MKR yes they do exist in Shapefile as well, some of them not to same extent but the one I showed in my original post has the overlap in Shapefile as well